# SVG set to fill currentColor but doesn't update in high contrast mode

Tags: html, css, svg, high-contrast

I have a couple in-line SVGs on my webpage. Here's an example of one:

```css
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25px" viewBox="-13 0 120 30" width="74px">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M20,12.82H24.6v8.31h8.52V12.82h4.62v21H33.12V25.39H24.6v8.43H20Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M42.78,12.82H58.62v4.11H47.37v4.26h9.9V25.3h-9.9v4.41h11.4v4.11h-16Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M62.88,12.82H67.5v16.8H78v4.2H62.88Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M81.45,12.82H90c5,0,8,3,8,7.26v.06c0,4.86-3.78,7.38-8.49,7.38H86.07v6.3H81.45Zm8.28,10.59c2.31,0,3.66-1.38,3.66-3.18v-.06C93.39,18.1,92,17,89.64,17H86.07v6.42Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
</svg>
```

My understanding is this should allow Windows' High Contrast mode to adjust the fill of the SVG. However, while everything else on the page changes in high contrast mode, neither SVG changes its fill color. It is taking on the initial currentColor, but then never changes. Any ideas?

Comment: I thought SVGs were 'immune' to High Contrast Mode - but is there some thought that if currentColor is used it would come under High Contrast changes?

Comment: Yeah, these were some of the articles I read that mentioned using currentColor in order to make them work with high contrast mode:
- https://sarahmhigley.com/writing/whcm-quick-tips/
- https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2018-12-24-making-single-color-svg-icons-work-in-dark-mode
- https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/17/styling-for-windows-high-contrast-with-new-standards-for-forced-colors/
It's totally possible I've misunderstood it since I'm a newbie to all this!

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen this and agree it sounds as though filling with currentColor should be affected but running your SVGs on Windows10/Edge in High Contrast Mode on my laptop it isn't. Let's hope someone who understands this can answer here.

Comment: I have just tried your SVG with IE11 on Windows 10 and High Contrast Mode set and the color does change (in this case from black to white) so I have a nasty feeling the articles you cited applied to Edge pre its going Chromium but I don't have full proof. Can you test for forced color? Even then I don't know that you can know whether a darker or lighter color that you should be using, given the user has a wide choice.

Comment: Ah darn, you're right. It does work in Explorer and Firefox, but not Chrome (where I was testing it).

Comment: I suspect we have to resort to finding out more about forced color which at least has the merit of being on a standards track I think - but I don't understand how it tells you what to do SVG-wise in terms of make darker or lighter....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but as I understand the issue, the following example should work when changing to High Contrast Mode. The color property on the parent element (body) controls the fill in the SVG. When the color is "overwritten" this will also affect the SVG.

```css
body {
  color: DarkSlateBlue;
  background-color: MidnightBlue;
}

svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Text example</p>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25px" viewBox="-13 0 120 30" width="74px">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M20,12.82H24.6v8.31h8.52V12.82h4.62v21H33.12V25.39H24.6v8.43H20Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M42.78,12.82H58.62v4.11H47.37v4.26h9.9V25.3h-9.9v4.41h11.4v4.11h-16Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M62.88,12.82H67.5v16.8H78v4.2H62.88Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M81.45,12.82H90c5,0,8,3,8,7.26v.06c0,4.86-3.78,7.38-8.49,7.38H86.07v6.3H81.45Zm8.28,10.59c2.31,0,3.66-1.38,3.66-3.18v-.06C93.39,18.1,92,17,89.64,17H86.07v6.42Z" transform="translate(-19.98 -12.82)" />
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately while this is true for IE11 and used therefore to be true for Edge it is not true for current Edge or Chrome. (see comments on the question).